# why post json not working with ajax?what should i do

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

is anything wrong with my code?
cause it goes to error part when i run it

please help me
im still an amateur here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
            var name = $('#inputFname').val();
            var family = $('#inputLname').val();
            var username = $('#inputUname').val();
            var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
            var mobile = $('#inputMobile').val();
            var address = $('#inputEmail').val();
            if (name !== '' && family !== '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Registeration.aspx.cs/InsertUser",
                    data: "{'FirstName':'" + name + "' , 'LastName' : '" + family + "' , 'UserName' :'" + username + "' , 'Password':'" + password + "', 'Mobile': '" + mobile + "','Address': '" + address + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#inputFname').value('a');
                        $('#inputLname').value('a');
                        $('#inputUname').value('a');
                        $('#inputPassword').value('a');
                        $('#inputMobile').value('a');
                        $('#inputEmail').value('a');
                        alert("Registeration Complete");

                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert("Registeration Failed!");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Please fill all fields!");
                return false;
            }
        });
    })   

</script>
```

Comment: Telling us there is an error doesn't help, you need to explain exactly the error message. Maybe some basic debugging of this would also be useful.

Comment: i debugged it
it goes till the $.ajax part and after that it shows the error alert
i mean it wont goes into ajax part

Comment: 0

Are you sure the url is correct?

url: "Registeration.aspx.cs/InsertUser",
Shouldn't it be 'Registration.aspx' ?

Please post the exact error message that you get.

Comment: i try it without .cs but still doesnt work

Comment: Milad, if you console.log the error as mrQubeMaster says you do know where to view the results of the logging of that message correct?  You can view using the dev tools of whatever browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a `string` data instead of `JSON`

```
data: "{'FirstName':'" + name + "' , 'LastName' : '" + family + "' , 'UserName' :'" + username + "' , 'Password':'" + password + "', 'Mobile': '" + mobile + "','Address': '" + address + "'}"
```

You should change that to `JSON` format,

```
data: {
    FirstName:name, 
    LastName:family, 
    UserName: username, 
    Password:password, 
    Mobile:mobile,
    Address:address
    }
```

That code should be like

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
        var name = $('#inputFname').val();
        var family = $('#inputLname').val();
        var username = $('#inputUname').val();
        var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
        var mobile = $('#inputMobile').val();
        var address = $('#inputEmail').val();
        if (name !== '' && family !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Registeration.aspx.cs/InsertUser",
                data: {
                   FirstName:name, 
                   LastName:family, 
                   UserName: username, 
                   Password:password, 
                   Mobile:mobile,
                   Address:address
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#inputFname').value('a');
                    $('#inputLname').value('a');
                    $('#inputUname').value('a');
                    $('#inputPassword').value('a');
                    $('#inputMobile').value('a');
                    $('#inputEmail').value('a');
                    alert("Registeration Complete");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Registeration Failed!");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please fill all fields!");
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: it doesnt goes to ajax part at all when i debug it

Comment: You should let us know the error you got, Then only we can identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

if your ajax goes to the error section of the call the response url has a problem processing. well, usually it does at least.
console.log the result of the error so we have an idea of the problem

```
error: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    }
```

also what banujan is saying makes sense.
you could also use .serialize() to get all the inputs from a form
`var str = $( "form" ).serialize();` 
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

edit:

```
$(function() {
        $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
            var name = $('#inputFname').val();
            var family = $('#inputLname').val();
            var username = $('#inputUname').val();
            var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
            var mobile = $('#inputMobile').val();
            var address = $('#inputEmail').val();
            if (name !== '' && family !== '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Registeration.aspx.cs/InsertUser",
                    data: $( "#formId" ).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#inputFname').value('a');
                        $('#inputLname').value('a');
                        $('#inputUname').value('a');
                        $('#inputPassword').value('a');
                        $('#inputMobile').value('a');
                        $('#inputEmail').value('a');
                        alert("Registeration Complete");

                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        console.log(result)
                        //the result var in this case returns the response from the website. usually this holds a error of some kind
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Please fill all fields!");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: where does the resault go?
i donno anything about javascript sry
im an amateur

Comment: no problem, we all had to learn this at some point. i added an example for you as i was not really sure if you meant the serialize or the error output. let us know if the problem persists

Comment: i did all these things u said but still nothing happened :(

Comment: i mean i added things that u said on ur example but nothing happens

Comment: not sure what you mean, created a small test script. is this not working in your code? it should alert the error https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqGZVE?editors=1010